Apache derby no suitable driver found
I'm developping a Java application and everything runs smooth on Eclipse.
This a maven project and no error in my pom.xlm.
When I export the project to a runnable JAR file, either by coping/packaging the required librairies, I receive this error : No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:D:\BD_CP_Java\dbCP.
Command ran : java -jar D:\BD_CP_Java\Recherche_CP.jar.
The location of the database is : D:\BD_CP_Java\dbCP
public ConnectionDB() throws SQLException {
    try {
        String dbURL = "jdbc:derby:D:/BD_CP_Java/dbCP";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
        setMinMaxDates();
    }catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        throw new SQLException();
    } 
}

I'm a bit lost and if someone can guide me towards what I'm missing here.
Thanks to all who will read this post.



coping/packaging the required librairies could you specify how do you package the jar? (and make sure if the driver is included in the target jar file). If not, you may need to specify the classpath to the driver library java -cp path_to_driver_jar ....

@gusto2 I used Eclipse to generate the JAR file. (File/Export/Java/Runnable JAR file. How can I make sure that the driver is included ? I thought Maven will take care of that.

I'd suspect the the driver is not included in the package. The eclipe will not include any external libraries. Ëxecutable jar just means the main-class is specified. You may need to either either use a shader (mvn plugin packaging all jars together, but it may break other things), I prefer putting all jars next to each other and specify relative path to them
As well - I don't like absolute path on databases or libraries, mainly with windows notation. I'd suggest using relative path with  unix notation, it will make your app more portable

Are you using Derby as an embedded database or as a server-based database? Refer to Deployment options in the Getting Started guide. The required [JDBC driver] JAR file depends on how you are using Derby.

Embedded database.

It would be better to make your "fat jar" (jar file including your application's classes and the classes of all of your dependencies via maven instead of relying on your IDE to do it.
See this SO answer: Building a fat jar using maven

I will give it a try. The thing is, I've switched from my work laptop to my personnal gaming pc. I exported the same project via Eclipse and ... booom !! Everything works! I tried to run the same JAR file back to my laptop and same error ... "No suitable driver found. I'm so confused !

Yes, that is pretty confusing.
If you update the maven build to make a "fat jar" and make sure that the derby driver jar file is included, it should work predictably in both environments.
Having a stable build with no manual intervention is the way to avoid "it works on my machine" syndrome :-)
Even better, run your build in a fresh environment each time, like maybe put your project on GitHub, and use GitHub actions to run the build...

I did what you were suggesting, I used Maven shade plugin. It runs smoothly on my personnal PC but same error on my work laptop. "No suitable driver found". I've tried different versions of the Apache Derby jar files with no lucks.  The command I used "java -cp CP-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.CP.MainUserInterface". Do you think it has something to do with the fact that i'm just a standard user (no admin rights) on my work laptop ?

@Vini nothing to do with the admin... is not the problem with the database path? (back-slash?) Or plz check what's inside the JAR, if the driver is included (the jar file is actually an ordinary ZIP file).

@gusto2 Thank you again. Either slashes or backslashes give the same error with the no suitable driver found.  I just updated my question by adding 2 pictures (manifest and the content of the jar). Any insight ?  I would like to add that my work laptop has Java version 1.8 (Java 8) installed.

I finally found why it wasn't working. I've created the derby database with derby.jar version 10.17.1.0 because it was the lastest one. That directly comes in conflict with the Java version installed on my PC 1.8 wich what release in 2014. I've recreated my DB with derby.jar version 10.10.1.1 (version released in 2013) and now everything works perfectly. The thing i'm asking myself, is why it was working inside Eclipse but not when the project was packed. Well... thanks for all your time and your help ... and happy coding.
